# How the nusoap return array?

Tags: php, arrays, soap, nusoap

I write server.php as below:

```
require_once("lib/nusoap.php");
require_once("connect.php");

$server = new soap_server;

$server->configureWSDL('server', 'urn:RM');

$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'game',
    'complexType',
    'struct',
    'all',
    '',
    array(
     'eventId'=>array('name'=>'eventId','type'=>'xsd:int'),
     'eventName'=>array('name'=>'eventName','type'=>'xsd:string'))
    );

$server->register('gamelist',
    array('id'=>'xsd:int'),
    array('return'=>'tns:game'),
    'urn:RM',
    'urn:RM#gamelist',
    'rpc',
    'encoded',
    'Get Games Info');

function gamelist($id){
 $query="select eventId, eventName from jos_games where parentId='$id'";
 $rs=mysql_query($query);

 $game=array();
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
  $game[]= $row;
 }
 //print_r($game);
 return $game;
}


$HTTPRAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA:"";  
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

---

client.php as below:

```
require_once("lib/nusoap.php");

$client =  new nusoap_client('http://sonia.ecisoft.com/soap/server.php');


if($err=$client->getError()){
 echo 'Error:'.$err;
}

$id=1;
$return = $client->call('gamelist', array('id'=>$id));

print_r($return);
```

---

I can't get return from client.php. I want to list rows of eventId, eventName.
Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Have you checked whether the server returns a valid response if you simply query the URL in the browser (or even a tool like SOAPUI)? That will tell you whether its your client or server which is at fault.

Comment: I try print_r($game) in server.php, it is right. And I try 
echo "<xmp>".$client->request."</xmp>";
echo "<xmp>".$client->response."</xmp>";
The soap response print_r array.

Answer (score 6):

I think the PHP type should be "array". Changing the following, should work.

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
'game',
'complexType',
'array',
'all',
'',
array(
 'eventId'=>array('name'=>'eventId','type'=>'xsd:int'),
 'eventName'=>array('name'=>'eventName','type'=>'xsd:string'))
);
```

The return value of function gamelist should be like this:

```
return array("game" => $game);
```

Answer (score 4):

Add Complex type of list Array

```
$soap->wsdl->addComplexType(
 'ListArray',
 'complexType',
 'array',
 '',
 'SOAP-ENC:Array',
  array(),
  array(
    array('ref'=>'SOAP-ENC:arrayType','wsdl:arrayType'=>'xsd:string[]')
  ),
  'xsd:string'
```

);

Register Function

```
        $soap->register(
"YourAPIName",
array( ),
array('return' => 'tns:ListArray'),
API_NAMESPACE,
false, false, false,
```

)